# How to attach a presenter to a derived control (view) using Mosby?

Tags: android, mosby

I'm otherwise successful using Mosby in my app. I'm now at the point where I'd like to add a presenter to a `NavigationView` control. I've overridden the control to encapsulate view-ish things such as adding menu items and dynamically appearing child controls.

I would now like to move all of the presenter-ish code from the `MainActivity.java` into a `NavigationDrawerPresenter` class and I'd like to use Mosby.

I've read through the Mosby docs and I didn't see where it explains how to attach a presenter to a View control that I've extended from the SDK that is sitting deep inside of a Activity layout. I gathered that I could use the ViewGroupMvpDelegateImpl directly and manually delegate all of the lifecycle events from the view to the delegate.  (Is this the right way?)

In the case of the `NavigationView`, this is problematic.

`NavigationView` inherits from `ScrimInsetsFrameLayout`.  It doesn't let us override `onAttachedToWindow` or `onDetachedFromWindow`.  It responds with:

`ScrimInsetsFrameLayout.onAttachedToWindow can only be called from within the same library group (groupId=com.android.support)`

This seems to be a showstopper for Mosby.  Without this override, I don't know how to attach Mosby's delegate to the lifecycle events.

**How do I attach a presenter to a view that I have extended from the Android SDK?**

```
    public class NavigationDrawerView extends NavigationView
        implements NavigationDrawerContract.View,
        ViewGroupDelegateCallback<NavigationDrawerContract.View, NavigationDrawerContract.Presenter>, MvpView,
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    protected ViewGroupMvpDelegate<NavigationDrawerContract.View, NavigationDrawerContract.Presenter> mvpDelegate;
        protected NavigationDrawerContract.Presenter presenter;

    //...

        public NavigationDrawerView(Context context) {
            super(context);
        }

        public NavigationDrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }

        public NavigationDrawerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }

    //...

    @NonNull
        protected ViewGroupMvpDelegate<NavigationDrawerContract.View, NavigationDrawerContract.Presenter> getMvpDelegate() {
            if (mvpDelegate == null) {
                mvpDelegate = new ViewGroupMvpDelegateImpl<>(this, this, true);
            }

            return mvpDelegate;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onAttachedToWindow() {
            super.onAttachedToWindow();
            getMvpDelegate().onAttachedToWindow();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDetachedFromWindow() {
            super.onDetachedFromWindow();
            getMvpDelegate().onDetachedFromWindow();
        }

    //...
    }

public class NavigationDrawerPresenter
    extends MvpNullObjectBasePresenter<NavigationDrawerContract.View>
    implements NavigationDrawerContract.Presenter {

//...
}

public interface NavigationDrawerContract {
    interface View extends MvpView {
        // ...
    }

    interface Presenter extends MvpPresenter<View> {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Comment: any update on this topic?
IMO, it is stupid to hide global hooks like `onAttachedToWindow` and `onDetachedFromWindow`.

Comment: Usually you just have to delegate `onAttachedToWindow()` and `onDetachedFromWindow()` to the ViewGroupDelegate(). Since those methods are final, you have to use `addOnAttachStateChangeListener()` as a work around as pointed out by @guness (see answer below)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, I have faced same problem. I think we can use

```
 addOnAttachStateChangeListener(object : OnAttachStateChangeListener {
        override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(v: View?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

        override fun onViewAttachedToWindow(v: View?) {
            TODO("not implemented") //To change body of created functions use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    })
```